# Can I use my own filename when using NSTemporaryDirectory

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am generating a PDF file and saving it to my device before e-mailing it from within my application.  At the moment it does not get cleared down either manually or automatically so I was looking at NSTemporaryDirectory.  I have looked at various sites and also on here for the answer to my specific query but cannot find it.

I have the following function:

```
+(NSString *)getTempFilePathName {
    NSString *tempFilePathName = nil;
    NSString *tempFileTemplate = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tempfile.XXXXXX"];
    const char *tempFileTemplateCString = [tempFileTemplate fileSystemRepresentation];
    char *tempFileNameCString = (char *)malloc(strlen(tempFileTemplateCString) + 1);
    strcpy(tempFileNameCString, tempFileTemplateCString);
    int fileDescriptor = mkstemp(tempFileNameCString);
    if (fileDescriptor != -1) {
        // File opened successfully
        tempFilePathName = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] stringWithFileSystemRepresentation:tempFileNameCString length:strlen(tempFileNameCString)];
        close(fileDescriptor);
    }
    free(tempFileNameCString);

    return tempFilePathName;    
}
```

This returns me an NSString with the full path and filename to a temp file ending with the 'XXXXXX' component of the filename replaced with unique combo of letters and numbers.  As I am using this to save a PDF file, I need to fix the 'XXXXXX' bit with the extension ".PDF".  Preferably I'd like to also specify the filename itself too so something like "Order-123.PDF".

Can I just edit my method to pass in a filename and use that in the stringByAppendingPathComponent parameter?  Is the directory name generated unique per call to this method?

Comment: I have to ask why? The whole point of the temp directory is you keep the file open as long as you need it and then all bets are off. If you want to refer to the file again, the cached folder might be a better choice.

Comment: The file I'm generating is created and emailed, then never needs to be accessed again.  So happy to have iOS put it in this place where it automatically gets cleaned up after 3 days or so.  So this is I thought, the best way to do it.  Only issue being that it needed a PDF extension so that the emailed file would be recognised properly and able to be loaded by whoever received it without having to rename it.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by myself.  After the line that calls the above routine I do:

```
NSString *newFilePath = [tempNameStub stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"pdf"];
```

Which adds `.pdf` to the end.